# Apple: app requests the user’s consent to access the location, but doesn’t sufficiently explain the use of the location

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, core-location, appstore-approval, inappbrowser

Apple has rejected the app due to this:

> Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage

> We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access the location, but doesn’t sufficiently explain the use of the location in the purpose string.

> To help users make informed decisions about how their data is used, all permission request alerts need to specify how your app will use the requested information.

But we do not use any location service on the app. Apple mentioned screen is coming through the 3rd party web app. i.e. we have used "In-app browser" here. Since we cannot control the Location text on the 3rd party PWA app we cannot do anything here. So can you tell us how to overcome this kind of situation?

Reson from the Apple:

i.e. this shows on the in-app browser. not our app's message. no control from our side

[image]

Comment: *we have used "In-app browser" here* ... are you allowing users to go to **any** website they want? Or are you only showing a specific website that doesn't provide any way for the user to navigate to any other websites?

Comment: @DonMag This is a `ReadOnly` browser. i.e. no one can change the URL of this browser.

Comment: OK - this is off-topic for Stack Overflow, and I don't work for Apple, so just a comment... Either A) tell the website developer to ***NOT*** use location services, or B) present a view in your app ***before*** using the *"In-app browser"* clearly explaining that the user will be shown a web-page that will ask for Location Permissions, and describe *why* it will do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tested putting in a `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`, `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`, `NSLocationUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in your `Info.plist`?

It might override the 3rd party's so you can make it more detailed but you have to include their privacy policy in yours. Since ultimately whatever they do is your responsibility.

I would be skeptical about using a 3rd party that requires location for a browser.

Comment: I'll do that and will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: If just changing the Info.plist doesn’t work request it just before they do. Because the request method only runs once by the time it gets to their request you would have already called it.

Answer (score 1):

The text shown in this alert, "Allow Geolocation," is probably provided by the Ionic Framework (based on your tags). While you didn't write this code, it's still code you're providing (rather than Apple) so it's your responsibility.

Like Lorem Ipsum said, you might be able to override the text yourself - by that method or another method – but regardless the responsibility is on you to manage your libraries and dependencies, even though you didn't write them.